# Replace SID Value data in a href elements menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I want to replace all this SID=xxxx to SID=yyyy in my menu

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="http://localhost:11111/controller1/action1?SID=21212121">Menue 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://localhost:11111/controller1/action2?SID=21212121">Menue 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://localhost:11111/controller1/action3?SID=21212121">Menue 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I got from my callback a new SID value to replace the old value

```
$http.post(sUrl,sPostData).then(function(controller1Response) {
 $scope.result = controller1Response.data.ResultSet.result;
 $scope.SID = controller1Response.data.ResultSet.SID;

});
```

The $scope.SID got new new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```js
var newSID = '45454545'
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href').replace(/SID=[0-9]+/g, 'SID=' + newSID);
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="http://localhost:11111/controller1/action1?SID=21212121">Menue 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://localhost:11111/controller1/action2?SID=21212121">Menue 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://localhost:11111/controller1/action3?SID=21212121">Menue 3</a></li>
</ul>
<button id='btn'>click me</button>
```